# Why mysql_real_escape_string not working in this code?

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

Why `mysql_real_escape_string` not working in this code ?

Normally, when load page input will be look like this.

```
http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/ie/160812064246.jpg
```

But When you load page `www.example.com/test.php?value_1=">`

Why input look like this.

```
http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/ia/160812064312.jpg
```

How can i do ?

test.php

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$ex_search_value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value_1']);
?>

<input placeholder="PLEASE ENTER" value="<?PHP echo $ex_search_value; ?>" style=" margin: 0px; width: 810px;height: 33px;line-height: 17px;line-height: 33px\0;^line-height: 33px;padding: 0px;margin-right: -1px;padding-left: 5px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); ">
```

Comment: you really should not be using mysql API any more

Comment: You have to pass connection variable in `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_real_escape_string` escapes data so you can safely put it in an SQL query that you then send to MySQL. (NB: [`mysql_real_escape_string` is part of an obsolete API you should have stopped using about half a decade ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068).)

> ```
> value="<?PHP echo $ex_search_value; ?>"
> ```

That is not SQL. That is HTML, which you send to a web browser.

HTML is a different language to SQL. The escaping rules are different, not even subtly different, they are completely different.

You need to use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape data so it is suitable for inserting into HTML.

Answer (score -2):

mysql API is deprecated, you really should not be using it try to use mysqli

this is the syntax
`mysqli_real_escape_string(connection,escapestring);`
it takes the connection object and the string you want to escape

a good example is this

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

  // escape variables for security
  $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
  $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
  $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);

  $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
  VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
  echo "1 record added";
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Absolutely wrong, `mysql_real_escape_string` can be the worst thing ever but it takes only 1 argument, not 2. Function used here is `mysqli` based